# is localhost considered a NETBIOS name?

Tags: language, netbios

NETBIOS computer name is **host** name.

is "localhost" considered NETBIOS name?

for example local computer name is "CORP-DESKTOP", CORP-DESKTOP is NETBIOS name, is localhost NETBIOS name as well?

For example, some function deals with NETBIOS names, is it valid design to handle localhost in such function? or should the caller supply NETBIOS name explicitly to such function, ex. it should do name conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost is not a NETBIOS name.

From Wikipedia
[localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

> localhost is a hostname that refers to the current device used to access it. It is used to access the network services that are running on the host via the loopback network interface. Using the loopback interface bypasses any local network interface hardware.

The loopback interface is not related to NETBIOS and is only known
inside its own computer.
Both are quite distinct mechanisms in Windows.